# Unable To Search with Image In Search Bar Table View Cell: Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a table which has a name and a picture in each cell. I have a search bar which searches through the names which does successfully happen however the images are blank. When you erase your search from the search bar, the images in the cell also do disappear! Would anyone know what I have done wrong and if so can someone please help me out!

Thank you

- Had an issue with when search is deleted images are not shown but now it is fixed thanks to Raja
- Only issue left is that it does not filter images when searched. Images are still blank when the cells are searched

```
import UIKit

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var userWorkoutName: UILabel!

    var valueToPass: String!

    var workoutName = ["Apple","Orange","Banana"]
    
    var workoutImage = ["A","O","B"] 
    
    var searchingWorkouts = [String()]
    
    var searching = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchingWorkouts = workoutName
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if searching {
           return searchingWorkouts.count
        } else {
            return workoutName.count
        }
    
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cellIentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIentifier, for: indexPath) as! WorkoutTableViewCell
                        
        if searching {
            
            cell.workoutName.text =  searchingWorkouts[indexPath.row]
            cell.workoutImage.image = UIImage(named: searchingWorkouts[indexPath.row])
            
        } else {
            
            cell.workoutName.text =  workoutName[indexPath.row]
            cell.workoutImage.image = UIImage(named: workoutImage[indexPath.row])
            
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let moreDetail = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "UploadWorkoutViewController") as! UploadWorkoutViewController
        
       if searching {
            
            moreDetail.getWorkoutTitle = searchingWorkouts[indexPath.row]
            
     } else {
            
            moreDetail.getWorkoutTitle = workoutName[indexPath.row] 
            
        }
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(moreDetail, animated: true)
        
    }  
}

extension TestTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        searchingWorkouts = workoutName.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText } )
        
        searching = true

    if searchText.isEmpty {
            searching = false
        } else {
            searching = true
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()     
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add one extra condition like ``` if searchText.isEmpty { searching = false } else { searching code here } reload your table here```

Comment: Hi Raja, thank you for your input. I have implemented this and it solves the fact that when someone deletes their search images are shown (which was an issue before) so I thank you for that!

Comment: When deleting in search image at that time you also need to remove this image in the main array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are blank because you're not filtering the images, you're only filtering the workout names. And while searching you're assigning `searchingWorkouts` to image, which is totally wrong.

```
cell.workoutImage.image = UIImage(named: searchingWorkouts[indexPath.row])
```

Just like maintaining the `searchingWorkouts`, you need to maintain the `searchingWorkoutImage` as well. And then change the above line to this

```
cell.workoutImage.image = UIImage(named: searchingWorkoutImage[indexPath.row])
```

But the question is how will you filter the image names? Because workout names and image names are different.

So a better solution is to create a `Workout` class with `name` and `image` properties and change your code to the following

```
class Workout {
    var name: String = ""
    var image: String = ""
    
    init(name: String, image: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
}

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var userWorkoutName: UILabel!

    var valueToPass: String!
    
    var workouts = [Workout(name: "Apple", image: "A"), Workout(name: "Orange", image: "O")]
    var searchingWorkouts = [Workout]()
    
    var searching = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchingWorkouts = workouts
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if searching {
           return searchingWorkouts.count
        } else {
            return workouts.count
        }
    
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cellIentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIentifier, for: indexPath) as! WorkoutTableViewCell
                        
        if searching {
            
            cell.workoutName.text =  searchingWorkouts[indexPath.row].name
            cell.workoutImage.image = UIImage(named: searchingWorkouts[indexPath.row].image)
            
        } else {
            
            cell.workoutName.text =  workouts[indexPath.row].name
            cell.workoutImage.image = UIImage(named: workouts[indexPath.row].image)
            
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let moreDetail = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "UploadWorkoutViewController") as! UploadWorkoutViewController

       if searching {

        moreDetail.getWorkoutTitle = searchingWorkouts[indexPath.row].name

     } else {

        moreDetail.getWorkoutTitle = workouts[indexPath.row].name

        }

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(moreDetail, animated: true)
        
    }
}

extension TestTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        searchingWorkouts = workouts.filter({$0.name.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText } )
        
        searching = true

    if searchText.isEmpty {
            searching = false
        } else {
            searching = true
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I understand what I was doing wrong and this helped me solve the issue. Thank you very much!